# Looking for a historical fiction novel set in norse history

Tags: story-identification, alternate-history

Well, what I remember was the MC was a Viking that went from his homeland abroad(i forget if it was to gain experience or due to a succession crisis) and travels to many places, including meeting some central americans. he returns home and uses what he learned to assume the throne and lead his people to prosperity. He finishes his life sacrificing himself to Odin as part of a rite for prosperity. Also, this would be an older book since the copy I read was an older style cloth hardcover.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Are there any science fiction or fantasy elements in this story?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the story being asked about doesn't appear to contain any science fiction or fantasy elements.

Comment: Note that alternate history, even absent advanced technology, can still be on-topic.  Consider Baxter's *Times Tapestry* series, for instance, among many others.

Comment: Seems possibly on-topic to me.  Just change the title to "alternate history" rather than "historical fiction".